# Trying the docker mysql image but user/password does not work

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a simple docker setup using php7 and mysql, both from docker hub. Setting up is ok so far, everything starts up and I can access my app. But I can't get the mysql connect to work for me. I even logged in into the box and tried accessing the db, but it fails. Anybody any idea?

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  restart: always
  image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_USER: myapp
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: myapp
    MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
web:
  restart: always
  image: silintl/php7
  command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /app/web
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  volumes:
    - ../:/app
```

trying to access the db

```
[bash]marcobehnke@Marcos-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ $ docker exec -it docker_db_1 bash

[root@7eff3007bb11 /]# mysql --user=myapp --password=myapp --host=localhost --port=3306 myapp
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@7eff3007bb11 /]#
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: Have a look at my github repo, this is the exact config I am using: https://github.com/firegate666/docker-php7-mysql-postgres

Comment: Have you gone through the usual debugging e.g. can you connect as root? Also, there are some detailed [guidelines](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) - it's worth considering what it says under "*No connections until MySQL init completes*" and "*Usage against an existing database*", because either of those could be affecting your system here.

Comment: yes, tried that but root isn't connecting as well and I have waited quite some time to let mysql init, but still can't connect and it is a new database

Comment: OK, that's useful. Also, have you checked in the docker container log for any clues?

Comment: In the container logs there is nothing and the only thing from the mysql log is `2016-09-01T09:03:38.200658Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'myapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I took a different machine and tried my setup, it worked out of the box. I have no idea whyt this is about, but the problem is obviously my machine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using the [wrong syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/environment). Should look something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    MYSQL_USER: "myapp"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "myapp"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "myapp"
  # ...
```

Comment: The documentation (that you link to) suggests that either syntax is correct (using a colon or an equals sign); it gives examples of both, and explicitly says "*You can use either an array or a dictionary*".

Comment: Yes, but then you have to use strings. I tried your solution and it produces "invalid type, it should be a string".

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't help

    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=myapp
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=myapp
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@7eff3007bb11 /]#

Comment: I tested exactly the first part of my answer and pasted it to a docker-compose.yml file. Then started it: `docker-compose up` and connected to it: `docker exec -it mysql_db_1 mysql --user=myapp --password=myapp`

Comment: :-( I don't get it. I copy/pasted your solution incl. version and services. But it is still failing `docker exec -it docker_db_1 mysql --user=myapp --password=myapp --host=localhost --port=3306 myapp
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` - I hate it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/37nezmhL this is my docker-compose.yml file located in the directory `mysql`. Then `docker-compose up` and connect to it: `docker exec -it mysql_db_1 mysql --user=myapp --password=myapp`. There is another problem with your code, since the folder `/app` does not exist, but I can connect to the database

Comment: The /app folder is mounted as you can see in the web image. I pushed my docker folder to github, there you can find the exact configuration I am trying. I have set a config with a postgres and one with mysql. postgres works with the environment variables, mysql not --- :-(  `https://github.com/firegate666/docker-php7-mysql-postgres`

Comment: I sent you a pull request.